# Is there any function to choose multiple items from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to create a password (with a specific length) by choosing items randomly from 3 lists (`UPPER_case`, `lower_case` & `digits`) without repeating the same item.
My problem is when I use `random.sample(lists, length)` it my take all `items(length)` from just one or two lists

```py
def pass_maker(length, flagUpper, flagLower, flagDigit):
    ...
    ...
    if flagUpper == True and flagLower == True and flagDigit == False:
        return ''.join(random.sample((let_upp + let_low), length))
    elif flagUpper == True and flagLower == True and flagDigit == True:
        return ''.join(random.sample((let_upp + let_low + digits), length))
```

e.g : `python pass_maker(2, True, False, True)`, I expect : `A2` o `1P` but it may results `BB` without digits or `57` without upper case letters. The same problem for the other conditions.
[result error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEx34.png)

Comment: "without repeating the same item", do you mean that the password cannot use the same letter or number twice? Getting 'BB' with `random.sample()` is unlikely, unless `B` appears in two of the lists. What have you tried to get at least one value from every list? (because your code does nothing to do that)

Comment: Yes, and choosing items from lists according to the flags

Answer (score 0):

One easy (if not very optimally performing) option:

```
import random


def pass_maker(length, charsets):
    # have to be at least as many characters in the result as the number of sets
    assert length >= len(charsets)
    # can be no more characters in result than in the combined sets
    assert length <= sum([len(charset) for charset in charsets])

    # first pick one from each charset
    ones = [random.choice(charset) for charset in charsets]
    # combine all the rest into a big collection, to ensure equal likelihood
    rest = [c for charset in charsets for c in charset if c not in ones]
    # shuffle them
    random.shuffle(rest)
    # take the number needed, i.e. length minus the number already taken
    result = ones + rest[:length-len(ones)]
    # shuffle the result for random order
    random.shuffle(result)
    # turn the result into a string
    return ''.join(result)


# just generating and printing a bunch of results
for _ in range(10):
    print(pass_maker(3, [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]))

# what also works, since a string is also iterable
print(pass_maker(3, ['ABCD', 'abcd', '1234']))
```

Note: this is assuming the restriction that every character can only be used once, characters from each charset should be equally likely to appear in the answer.

I didn't like the function signature as provided in the question, but if you need that it would be something like:

```
let_upp = 'ABCD'
let_low = 'abcd'
digits = '1234'


def ugly_pass_maker(length, flag_upper, flag_lower, flag_digit):
    return pass_maker(length, [
        let_upp if flag_upper else [],
        let_low if flag_upper else [],
        digits if flag_upper else []
    ])


print(ugly_pass_maker(4, True, True, False))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out.